# Odoo12 ./odoo-bin run , first time installation OSX Traceback (most recent call last): File "./odoo-bin",

Tags: python, odoo

This my first time in Odoo, I use MacOS. Python 3.7 and Odoo12. I followed the steps, after installing pip3 install -r requirements.txt i use ./odoo-bin 
but I failed. it shows

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./odoo-bin", line 8, in <module>
    odoo.cli.main()
  File "/Users/Zubaer/.odoo.env/odoo/odoo/odoo/cli/command.py", line 60, in main
    o.run(args)
  File "/Users/Zubaer/.odoo.env/odoo/odoo/odoo/cli/server.py", line 176, in run
    main(args)
  File "/Users/Zubaer/.odoo.env/odoo/odoo/odoo/cli/server.py", line 124, in main
    odoo.tools.config.parse_config(args)
  File "/Users/Zubaer/.odoo.env/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/config.py", line 337, in parse_config
    odoo.netsvc.init_logger()
  File "/Users/Zubaer/.odoo.env/odoo/odoo/odoo/netsvc.py", line 133, in init_logger
    resetlocale()
  File "/Users/Zubaer/.odoo.env/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/translate.py", line 1201, in resetlocale
    for ln in get_locales():
  File "/Users/Zubaer/.odoo.env/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/translate.py", line 1170, in get_locales
    lang = locale.getdefaultlocale()[0]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 568, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 495, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2):

Try exporting the below to your ~/.bash_profile.

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8